# why doesn't the exception get printed?

Tags: java, c, exception, java-native-interface

The following is a *java* code and next to it is the *c* code :

```
package Package;

public class CatchThrow {

private native void doit() throws IllegalArgumentException;

private void callBack() throws NullPointerException {
    System.out.println("In call-back !");
    throw new NullPointerException("CatchThrow.callBack");
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    CatchThrow c = new CatchThrow();
    try {
        c.doit();
    } catch(Exception exc) {
        System.out.println("\nIn Java : \n\t" + exc);
    }
}

 static {
     System.loadLibrary("CatchThrow");
 }
}
```

C code :

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "Package_CatchThrow.h"

void Java_Package_CatchThrow_doit
   (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
  jthrowable exc;
  jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);
  jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"callBack","()V");
  if(mid == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env,obj,mid); // call the java method that throws NullPointerException
  printf("After the call to Call-Back !");
  exc = (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env);
  if(exc) {
    jclass newExcCls;
    printf("\n");
    //(*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);  ----> NOTE THE COMMENTED STATEMENT
    //(*env)->ExceptionClear(env);  -----> NOTE THE COMMENTED STATEMENT
    newExcCls = (*env)->FindClass(env,"java/lang/IllegalArgumentException");
    if(newExcCls == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    (*env)->ThrowNew(env,newExcCls,"thrown from c code");
  }
```

}

When i build and run the above program I get the following output :

```
In call-back !
After the call to Call-Back !

In Java :
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: thrown from c code
```

*From the output :*  C code calls the java function *callBack*. There the first statement gets printed. After the call returns the statement next to the call i.e `After the call to Call-Back !` gets printed. But what happened to the statement `throw new NullPointerException("CatchThrow.callBack");` in the java function *callBack* ? Why doesn't it print the exception ?

**But** if i remove the comments from the statements

```
(*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);
(*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
```

commented, I get the desired output :

```
In call-back !
After the call to Call-Back !
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: CatchThrow.callBack
    at Package.CatchThrow.callBack(CatchThrow.java:14)
    at Package.CatchThrow.doit(Native Method)
    at Package.CatchThrow.main(CatchThrow.java:20)

In Java :
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: thrown from c code
```

Why is that ?

What is the role of those two statements ? And why doesn't the exception get printed in the absence of those 2 statements ?

Comment: face the same problem. my jni code crash in `GetObjectClass` next to `CallVoidMethod`, instead of in function `CallVoidMethod`, which leads to a NullPointerException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your  `new NullPointerException("CatchThrow.callBack");` never touches the Java runtime and is handled completely in JNI space.

As such, no exception details will be printed unless you call the JNI ExceptionDescribe function:

```
(*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);
```

You can't return multiple exceptions from the JNI so the only exception information that comes back to your try/catch block in the Java runtime is the one you create later on with:

```
(*env)->ThrowNew(env,newExcCls,"thrown from c code");
```

> A pending exception raised through the JNI (by calling ThrowNew, for
>   example) **does not immediately disrupt the native method execution**.
>   This is different from how exceptions behave in the Java programming
>   language. When an exception is thrown in the Java programming
>   language, the virtual machine automatically transfers the control flow
>   to the nearest enclosing try/catch statement that matches the
>   exception type. The virtual machine then clears the pending exception
>   and executes the exception handler. In contrast, JNI programmers must
>   explicitly implement the control flow after an exception has occurred.

From the [JNI documentation on exceptions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/exceptions.html)

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by _JNI space_ ?

Comment: When you call a JNI function you are no longer within the Java Virtual Machine--you are in the native C code until the function returns. "Java™ has a clear and consistent strategy for the handling of exceptions, but C/C++ code does not. Therefore, the Java JNI does not throw an exception when it detects a fault. The JNI does not know how, or even if, the native code of an application can handle it."

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html), `ExceptionDescribe`

> Prints an exception and a backtrace of the stack to a system error-reporting channel, such as `stderr`. This is a convenience routine provided for debugging.

`ExceptionClear`:

> Clears any exception that is currently being thrown. If no exception is currently being thrown, this routine has no effect.

This is usually not what you want. I suggest to create `IllegalArgumentException` with the NPE as cause. In Java, you'd write this like so:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException( "thrown from c code", exc );
```

That way, the inner and outer exceptions (incl. stack traces) are available at the Java level where you can examine them.